# How to create a vim :map equivalent for vim's commands (eg: 2<<)?

Tags: vim

I tend to use vim a lot. Vim has a lot of commands which are not always easy to remember at first. `:map` displays a list of current mapping. I would like to get the same thing for normal-mode commands (see example hereafter)

`:cheatsheet` would display:

```
-------- vim-commands ----------------------------------------------------------
// BASIC CONTROL
hjkl        - move
i           - insert mode
R           - replace mode
o           - insert new line below
O           - insert new line above

// BASIC MOTIONS
0           - start of line
^           - start of text on line
$           - end of line

// WORD MOTIONS
w           - forwards a word
W           - forwards MORE
...
```

**a) Is there something similar for vim commands (eg: 2<< to indent 2 lines to the left) ?**

**b) If yes, how can one customize this output (say to only show the commands he/she has learned) ?**

Comment: It sounds like you want a listing of `normal`-mode commands, instead of `cmdline` commands?  I don't know of such a listing, but I would start by gathering a list of items in places like `:help motion.txt` and `:help change.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is create a cheat sheet as a Vim help file (e.g. `~/.vim/doc/cheat.txt`). You can use the Vim help markup, and after `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`, it's also indexed and accessible through `:help`. You can prepopulate it with fragments copied from the built-in help. Over time, add new tips and remove stuff that you've memorized.

Comment: This makes sense, I will try it out, it will also allow to learn the markup language.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `:viusage` but it can't be customized. You'll need to come up with your own solution for that.

***edit***

Note that there's also `:exusage` for listing Ex commands.

When I started, I took the habit of [adding new tricks to a file](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim/wiki/Notes) as I learned them. As it stands, the purpose of this habit was not to create a cheatsheet but to formalize what I learned; helping me committing all of that to memory. As times passed, the need to edit this file slowly vanished but I keep adding stuff from time to time. However, commands like the ones in your question don't really need to be put on a cheatsheet since you are doing them dozens of times a day.

Comment: Reading random `:help` files helps!